# How to allow CaptchaControl not a case sensitive in asp.net(both capital and small character should allow))

Tags: asp.net, validation, c#-4.0, captcha

CaptchaControl code like this

```
 <Captcha:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low"
                                            CaptchaLength="5" CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaLineNoise="None"
                                            CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240" FontColor="#529E00" />
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't a core ASP.Net component. Is this a Telerik control? Have you consulted the documentation for it?

Comment: i have added MSCaptcha.dll for this

Comment: MSCaptcha.dll is from Mondor Software, not Microsoft. http://kirsanov.net/page/ASPNET-CAPTCHA.aspx It doesn't look like there's much assistance that could be given here.